# How test SSH connectivity with expect script

Tags: linux, bash, tcl, expect

I have Linux red-hat machine - version 5.X

I want to create expect script that verify if ssh login to remote machine is successfully

my test is only to get the **password** prompt on remote login ( I not want to enter password )

its like to test **ssh** connectivity

what I created until now is the following script

so if I get password prompt then script need to return 0

if not then script need to return 1

the problem with my script is that - the script return 0 even ssh login is failed ( no password prompt )

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect


 set LOGIN      [lindex $argv 0]
 set PASSWORD   [lindex $argv 1]
 set IP         [lindex $argv 2]




 set timeout 10
 spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $LOGIN@$IP
 expect -re "(Password:|word:)"
 exit 0
 expect {
     timeout {error "incorrect password"; exit 1}
 eof
 }
```

please advice how to update my script ?

Comment: You will never be able to do an SSH keyboard interactive login via a shell script. The password must come from the keyboard. Use _secret key based_ authentication instead.

Comment: Expect simulates a keyboard. Yes, expect can do that.

Comment: Kuhn - so if expect can do that , can you show me by update my code what need to change in order to verify SSH login?

Comment: So then what do you expect from these two lines `expect -re "(Password:|word:)"` and `exit 0`? There's no instruction to send the password to the keyboard. The code just detects something on the prompt and exits.

Comment: Just for completeness there is now [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) which would replace such expect scipts. see e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/282319/how-to-use-sshpass

Comment: hi bdecaf  I prefer ti use expect script ,

Comment: @marekful: While there's no instruction in the code posted to send the password, it doesn't mean it can't be done. It can indeed be done: `expect {-re password: {send $PASSWORD}}`. Your claim that he will **never** be able to do it is false

Comment: @slebetman Well, I haven't known of this possibility and it certainly didn't exists some time ago. I don't doubt it exists now. Still, I argue that w/o instructing the code to _do send_ the password, the password will not be sent. This is correct and the OP op's code was written this way.

Comment: @marekful: Sending password to login prompt has been in the expect manual since the mid 90s. How long ago was some time ago? Also, the whole reason why the OP posted the question is to ask how to do it correctly. Of course his code doesn't work - it's good etiquette here on SO to post non-working code so that others may spot the mistake and correct it.

Comment: @slebetman I didn't know about `expect`, mea maxima culpa! Still, questioning the OP why he wonders his code does nothing when he instructs it to _exit_ w/o doing anything is a very valid idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose the condition in one `expect` as,

```
set timeout 10
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $LOGIN@$IP
expect {
    timeout {puts "Timeout happened";exit 0}
    eof {puts "EOF received"; exit 0}
    -nocase "password:" {puts "SSH connection is alive for the host $IP"; exit 1}
}
```

Have a look at the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30802914/974155) which resembles your question.

Comment: what the meaning of the -nocase??

Comment: It is a flag to make the string match of the word `password:` as case insensitive.

Comment: ok , I have some remarks ( need to change the exit 0 to exit 1 and exit 1 to exit 0 ) because 0 mean ok state

Comment: second - need to change -nocase "password:" to expect -re "(Password:|word:)" because this prompt can be diff on the remote machine

Comment: That is what `-nocase` is all about. It can match case insensitive pattern of `password`.

Answer (score 0):

**sshlogin.expect :**

```
set timeout 60

spawn ssh [lindex $argv 1]@[lindex $argv 0]

expect "yes/no" { 
   send "yes\r"
   expect "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }
   } "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }

interact
```

**Usage :**

```
sshlogin.expect <host> <ssh user> <ssh password>
```

Comment: not work - because time out isnt  activated ( not return 0 or 1 ) its stuck

Comment: It's better to move the "yes/no" to the inner expect as well since it will typically only be asked once and never again