# Answer terminal prompt remotely. Pipe to a different shell session

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a scheduled job that runs on a ec2 instances. Due to some recent third party lib change the job nows requires user interaction and can't be run automatically anymore.

The job executes a script that will prompt user input. The input is not simple y/n, and can changes so we can just echo y | myscript.sh

Compromise - I still like to continue running this job automatically on schedule, but it will ping the oncall engineer to answer prompt. Is there a way to answer the prompt remotely? If thats not possible then the engineer can ssh into the ec2 instance, but the engineer still needs a way to pipe to the shell that's awaiting for answer.

Comment: `The input is not simple y/n, and can changes so` surely the input can be scripted. Even sms receival can be scripted. `Is there a way to answer the prompt remotely?` Sky the limit. From top of my head: write an application that creates a internet socket that listens for input that is forwarded to the application. A simple is to take the input from a temporary fifo.

Comment: In the days before `sshpass` the login / password thing was done with [expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198894/how-test-ssh-connectivity-with-expect-script) .. expect is still suitable to use for interactive dialogs (where there might be different questions possible) - just hand the password part of it to sshpass.